# I want to deploy a full node for cardano and use it with json rpc

Tags: blockchain, computer-science, cryptocurrency

I want to deploy a full node for cardano and use it with json rpc. I need to fetch details such as wallet details etc but constantly getting socket hang up. Please can anyone share a good approach

I want to deploy a full node for the cardano and use it with json rpc. I need to fetch details such as wallet details etc but constantly getting socket hang up. Please can anyone share a good approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install and synchronize the Cardano node on your server.
2. Configure JSON-RPC settings in `config.json`.
3. Optionally, set up TLS for secure communication.
4. Open the required ports and implement security measures.
5. Choose a programming language and use a JSON-RPC library to interact with the node.
6. Test JSON-RPC calls to fetch wallet details and other data.
7. Monitor your node's health and performance.
8. Keep your node software and dependencies updated.